# Translate language for multiple pdf to english

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, power-automate

I have a set of pdf documents in russian and I need to translate them to English. I need to automate this activity.

Currently I upload the document to Google Translate and get it translated but it takes a lot of time to do this and is not scalable.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: there are some pdf that have images in them, i need to first convert them to editable text pdf then translate the language of the text from Russian to English. Currently this process is done manually and takes a lot of time. I have the responsibility to automate this task and I have no clue on how to approach this.

Comment: Is this done on Office 365? If not, what platform or tools are available for you to use?

Comment: I get the files on sharepoint. Tools / plarform that I have access to are power automate, PDF Xchange Editor, office, python

Comment: Currently i convert the files from 'image pdf' to 'text pdf' using PDF Xchange editor OCR then save those files manually to a directory, then i upload each document one by one to google translate to convert the language from Russian to English.

Comment: Power Automate is a surprisingly powerful tool. I'll submit an answer that maybe will help. If not, we can talk in the comments there instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I am unfamiliar with translating documents, but this should get your basic architecture in the right direction).

Based on our brief exchange, I would recommend exploring sort of a process like this:

[image]

With that, you would host docs using a SharePoint List, where when a doc is added, a Power Automate flow would trigger and translate then re-write the doc. You could either use Microsoft's in-house extraction and translation software (or Automate steps/actions), or you could send an HTTP request to whatever client you would like. A Google search for translation or text extraction APIs reveals several options, including Google Translate.

If you don't have any requirements to use Google Translate (or something else), I would personally stick with the same brand of tech so that there's less headache of working with an outside client... but of course that's up to whatever your requirements are. You can initiative HTTP requests with the "HTTP" action.

[image: HTTP Requests]

---

Within Power Automate, you would use the "When an item is created" SharePoint trigger, then Encodian's "Extract Text from Image" (or something different depending on your file type).
[image: Extract Text from Image]

Then, simply take the output and toss it to Microsoft Translate, or an HTTP request to wherever you want
[image: Microsoft Translator]

You can then write the translated output to wherever you would like, another SharePoint List, a database, email, whatever.

#### Good Links

- Microsoft Translator API: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/translator-api/
- Blog on extrating data from documents: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Extract-data-from-documents-with-Microsoft-Flow/ba-p/370422